# we wed, we wedded, we were wed or we were wedded?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, tense-agreement, formal-language

Which usage tense and is more formal: we wed, we wedded, we were wed, or we were wedded??

Sentence example, "We wed on 
(insert past date and location)."

Answer (score 2):

There's no clear answer here, but for what it's worth the Oxford English Dictionary (albeit in an entry not updated since 1926) regards "wed" as "now only dialectal" both as a past tense and as a past participle.  The implication is that one should prefer "wedded", as it's the only standard form.  This is backed up by Fowler's Modern English Usage (1965 edition), which describes "wedded" as the standard form.

However, other, more recent sources such as Cambridge ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wed ) and Merriam-Webster ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wed ) specify both forms without comment.

More interestingly, Cambridge's only example uses the form "wed": "The couple eventually wed after an 18-year engagement."

Also, every one of the examples at Oxford Dictionaries Online uses "wed" as both the simple past and past participle ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wed ): "they wed a week after meeting", "they were wed in London", and many more examples.

The Oxford examples use "wedded" only in metaphorical contexts ("the government was wedded to ...") or where the past participle is used adjectivally ("wedded bliss").

In BrE, at least, "wed" is considered a fairly formal or literary word anyway, mainly found in newspaper headlines where space is at a premium.  (Cambridge marks "wed" as "literary" in its British edition, though not in its American edition.)

It may be that the potential overtones of journalese are stronger with the shorter form despite its popularity. I would opt for "We were wedded".

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an irregular verb changing into a regular verb in English; a natural language evolution. In older forms of English, what we consider *irregular* verbs were the common form. Less frequently used words started converging to our current conjugation rules, while more frequently used words were held on to.

Linguists that study this transformation believe *wed* will be the next common English word to change from an irregular to regular form.

Source: [How Some Words Get Forgetted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFW7orQsBuo)